# Trouble disabling top navigation drop down menu

Tags: magento2

I'm attempting to disable the navigation drop down menu on a store. Using the maximal depth setting in the stores configuration works however its a global setting which effects stores I would like to keep the menu active on. I also thought changing the expanded variable under topmenu.phtml to false would disable the feature but that has not worked either. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The MauroNigrele solution hides the nav menu but leaves the `nav-sections`. To completely remove the nav use this code:

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please this code in your default.xml file.

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove it by layout

- Create a Custom theme for that/those store(S)
- Remove the navigation from the layout:

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        ...
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />
        </referenceContainer>
        ...

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: @Rakesh you made an unnecessary edit `Magento_Theme` is the folder name you actual need to use

Comment: Thanks, but I just need to remove the drop down portion of the menu.

Comment: Do you want to show only the guest level categoríes?

Comment: If by guest, you mean the parent categories that are visible without hovering, then yes.

Comment: Ahahaha I meant 'first level' (autocomplete error)

Comment: Ok I guess that the question isn't clear enough. Please add the 'root' or 'first level' detail in  order to make the question usefull for other people. In that case you can modify the phtml directly, but i want to try something (make category top navigation by store) have you a clean environment to test it? If you can make a full test i would add another answer with that (experimental) approach